# What would be the benefit to have more Supreme Court Justices?

Tags: united-states, government, supreme-court, joe-biden

One thing Joe Biden has mentioned was adding more seat to the Supreme Court. Why would he suggest this? How would it benefit the Court?

Originally in 1789, [there were six total justices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_justices_of_the_Supreme_Court_of_the_United_States_by_seat#Additional_seats) (one Chief Justice and five Associate Justices). Seat #6 was added in 1807. Seats #7 and #8 were added in 1837, but in 1865 seat #7 was abolished. In 1863, seat #9 was added and the 10th seat (the last seat) was added in 1869.
Since none of us were alive to see any differences, we can only see what history tells us.

Comment: I reformatted and put your title question in the text to make it a Q answerable here

Comment: *One thing Joe Biden has mentioned was adding more seat to the Supreme Court. Why would he suggest this?* **Where did he "suggest" this?** "*[Biden Says He's 'Not A Fan' Of Expanding The Supreme Court](https://www.npr.org/2020/10/13/923213582/biden-says-hes-not-a-fan-of-expanding-the-supreme-court)*". He did create a commission to study options, but I am unaware of any statement suggesting a favorable view toward expansion of the Court.

Answer (score 4):

Ostensibly, adding justices to a court (called [Packing the Court](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Judicial_Procedures_Reform_Bill_of_1937)) is done to further "smooth" out represented ideologies, with the idea that more justices will lead to greater compromise, which should more accurately reflect the will of the electorate. In practice, it's rarely anything other than a purely partisan move.

As @Phoog pointed out in the comments, the workload of the court will tend to grow with time, and more justices can be added to compensate for the additional cases to some extent.

To clear up how this answer sounds, I'm trying to make this a neutral observation of the process as stands. I personally support packing the supreme court, as I feel partisan shenanigans brought the court to where it is today. That does not change the note I made about the process almost always being a partisan one. It does not matter which party does the packing.

Comment: You might also note that there is an additional argument to be made about the court's workload.

Comment: @phoog added in, very valid point.